# How to find current url for mobile testing in appium

Tags: appium

I am doing automation testing using appium selenium .Can anybody help me with finding current url for mobile driver . Tried with driver.getCurrentUrl() . it's not working

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to check the context of the app :
If context is native app , you cant get url of any screen.
If App context is having WEBVIEW you will get URL

How to check context :
Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        for (String contextName : contextNames) {
            System.out.println(contextNames);
}

You can switch to WEBVIEW using following code :
 if (contextName.contains("WEBVIEW")) {
                driver.context("WEBVIEW");
                driver.getCurrentUrl()
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I will try it & let you know